# How to deal with a space issue on directory

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch file script that copying files to another directory.
The following script is working if there is no space between 'In' and 'Progress'.

I need this script works even with a space in the directory.

EG:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET source=C:\Tun\In Progress\Newfolder
SET target=C:\Tun\In Progress\resultfolder
IF NOT EXIST %target% MD %target%
FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.txt) DO (
    MOVE "%%f" "%target%\%%~nxf"
    PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SET "source=C:\Tun\In Progress\Newfolder"
SET "target=C:\Tun\In Progress\resultfolder"
MD "%target%" 2>nul 
FOR %%f IN ("%source%\*.txt") DO (
    MOVE "%%~ff" "%target%\%%~nxf"
    PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL
)
```

You will need to quote every file/folder reference that could include spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET source="C:\Tun\In Progress\Newfolder"
SET target="C:\Tun\In Progress\resultfolder"
IF NOT EXIST %target% MD %target%
FOR %%f IN (%source%\*.txt) DO (
    MOVE "%%f" %target%\%%~nxf
    PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 
)
```

I think that is a solution